# Android: Save login and password for WebView (like Google Chrome)

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

I tried to use different settings for `WebViww`
like this:

```
checkoutWV.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
checkoutWV.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
checkoutWV.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
checkoutWV.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
checkoutWV.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
checkoutWV.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
checkoutWV.setClickable(true);
checkoutWV.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

But nothing works.

Is it possible to use standart function of Google Chrome in `WebView` and how - to call a pop-up window for saving the password?

Comment: Password saving was deprecated as of API 18, which is why it is not working for you http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setSavePassword(boolean)

Comment: @anthonycr and there is no other way to do something similar for API > 18?

Comment: no there is not, you would need to implement password saving yourself by injecting JavaScript into the WebView.